# When to open and close the connection to DB

Tags: sql, postgresql, jakarta-ee, connection

I'm coding in Java EE and I have some class that manage all the actions with my DB.

I was asking myself when should I open/close the connection with the DB.

Is it better to open and close it in each method ?
Or is it better to open it in the constructor and close it when I finished using my class ?

Thx

Comment: While this question is common, its too generic. Add some examples, or even expected scenarios, otherwise people will flag your question as "primarily opinion-based"... From the text: many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1):

there is no generic solution. all decisions depends of concrete task. you should remember next things:

1. every connect to the database is the application time. if your method will be called too often, your application will waste lot of time to connect and disconnect tasks and much more with the slow network. in case of rarely calls, it will not so important;
2. if your method connects to database in the constructor for the long time without any operations the connection may be dropped. this is not neccesary, but may cause of the network issues or database connections policy. so before every query should be checked with fast and simple operation like `select 'some random text' from dual`;
3. database resources is not infinite and total number of connections is limited. this limit can be very large, but it still exist. so, if your application can be used in parallel several (hungred, thousands) times, it may reach the limits with permanent connections.

if you have no information of future usage of method, I advise use time limited permament connection. it should be opened with first query and closed with timer if method did no queries through this connection for some time like 3-5 seconds. sure, any querier should check connection status before query. open it, if it closed, with touching the closing timer. and don't forget explicitly close connection at destructor.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you shouldn't be managing it in code.  Every EE server I've worked on has connection pooling to remove the need for you to care about this.  Basically you "open" the connection when you need and "close" it when you need.  Those words are in quotes because it is up to the pool to manage when a connection is truly opened and closed.

From a design perspective then use the connection only when you need it.  Object construction doesn't make sense - what if a method in the class doesn't get called for an hour?  What is the purpose of having it open when you don't need it?  So if a method needs a connection open and close it in the method.